# recursion function in php not working as expected

Tags: php, recursion

```
private function find_children ($parent_id, $children, &$result)
{              
    foreach ($children as $c)
    {            
        if ($c->parent_comment_id == $parent_id)
        {                
            $result[] = $c;
            $this->find_children($c->id, $children, $result);            
        }            
    }
    return;        
}
```

The above function is supposed to take a starting parent id and recursively go through an array of children nodes (really just an object with a unique id and a parent id) sorting them so that each node comes directly after it's parent (see below for sample data).

But for some reason, the function doesn't execute as I expect. I have the following data for testing.

```
id: 1 pid: 0 (the initial parent which is not in the children array passed to func. problem?)
id: 2 pid: 1
id: 3 pid: 2
id: 4 pid: 1
id: 5 pid: 3
id: 6 pid: 5
id: 7 pid: 4
id: 8 pid: 3
```

and want the following array returned:
1, 4, 7, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6

But instead, I get:
1, 2, 3, 5, 6

which, while they're in the right order, a few are missing.

I have not had the need to do recursion in many years, so likely I am missing something obvious, although not so obvious to myself.

In case anyone is wondering, or if it matters, I'm trying to build a q&a commenting system where every post can have multiple replies.

Thus:

```
initial post 
-reply to initial post #1
--reply to reply
-reply to initial post #2
-- reply to above
--- reply to above
--reply to #2
```

Comment: You loop through $children but then you loop through the _same_ $children array on each subsequent recursed call. Do you want to pass a different value of children to the recursed function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like a [Nested Set Tree](https://web.archive.org/web/20090213170024/https://www.edutech.ch/contribution/nstrees/). It should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When i run your function on the data you listed, i do get the order you described, but i'm not missing any items:

```
id: 1, pid:0
id: 2, pid:1
id: 3, pid:2
id: 5, pid:3
id: 6, pid:5
id: 8, pid:3
id: 4, pid:1
id: 7, pid:4
```

And this result is actually the tree structure you want, just ordered ascending by the id's. If you order your chhildren-array descending by the id's, then you actually do get the output you request:

```
id: 1, pid:0
id: 4, pid:1
id: 7, pid:4
id: 2, pid:1
id: 3, pid:2
id: 8, pid:3
id: 5, pid:3
id: 6, pid:5
```

You should make sure you get the data in descending order from your DB. For this non-DB test case, i fixed it by using the following before calling find_children():

```
function revCmpObjects($a, $b) { //Just a basic descending ordering by the id
   if ($a->id == $b->id) {
       return 0;
   }
   return ($a->id > $b->id) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($children, 'revCmpObjects'); //The actual sorting
```

Comment: Here is how I think the nodes should be displayed (if I could get the function working)

id 1, pid 0
- id 2, pid 1
-- id 3, pid 2
--- id 5, pid 3
---- id 6, pid 5
- id 4, pid 1
-- id 7, pid 4

notice how, while node 4 is second from the last in my list and node 2 and all of its children are above it.

Comment: You forgot id:9 in your list, but if you add that between id:3 and id:5, then you have the first output i posted. So i think you need to clearify some more. Is it actually just the tree depth you want added to each node?

Comment: But it is different. You have: 1, 4, 7, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6

While I have: 1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6, 4, 7

which, now that I look at it, is really only due to us ordering the id's different (low vs. high values)